# ¿Por que este codigo html y js no funciona en Internet explorer de microsoft?

Tags: javascript, html5

Estoy haciendo un menú desplegable, que al hacer click dos veces en la pantalla se active y aparesca donde se hiso el click:
Este es mi codigo **html:**

```
<script src="./js/PopupMenu.js"></script>
<h1>Toca dos veces la pantalla.</h1>
<script>
var p=new PopupMenu();
p.__INIT__("PopupMenu.");
for(let i=0;i<1000;i++)//No sirve si se coloca la palabla clave var. Porque se pasa por referencia.
p.createItem("Item "+i,()=>{
alert("Item "+i);
});

</script>
```

Y este es mi codigo **JavaScript:**

```
/*&lt;!--Este script lo guarde en una carpeta llamada js. con el nombre de PopupMenu.js--&gt;*/
class PopupMenu{
__INIT__(titulo){
var body=document.body;
this.a=0;
this.table=document.createElement("table");
body.appendChild(this.table);
this.table.style.cssText="position:fixed;top:60%;background-color:#fff;border:2px solid #000;width:auto;color:#000;display:none;overflow:visible;";
this.table.innerHTML="<tbody><tr><th><h1>"+titulo+"</h1></th></tr></tbody>";
var table=this.table;
var i;
body.addEventListener("dblclick",(event)=>{
if(!i){
table.style.display="block";
table.style.left=event.clientX+"px";
table.style.top=event.clientY+"px";
}
},false);
body.addEventListener("click",()=>{if(!i)table.style.display="none";},false);
table.addEventListener("mouseover",()=>{i=true;},true);
this.table.addEventListener("mouseout",()=>{i=false;},false);

}
createItem(texto,onclick){
this.a++;
var tr=document.createElement("tr");
var td=document.createElement("td");
const on="border:2px solid orange;background-color:#ff0;padding:5%;width:auto;",off="border:2px solid black;background-color:#f00;opacity:0.6;padding:2%;width:auto;",tem="opacity:1;padding:5%;background-color:#f00;border:2px solid black;width:auto;";
this.table.appendChild(tr);
tr.appendChild(td);
td.innerHTML=""+texto;
td.style.cssText=off;

td.onmouseover=()=>{
td.style.cssText=tem;
};
td.onmousedown=()=>{
td.style.cssText=on;
onclick();
};
td.onmouseout=()=>{
td.style.cssText=off;

};
td.onmouseup=()=>{
td.style.cssText=off;

};
td.onclick=()=>{
td.style.cssText=on;
}
td.touchstart=()=>{
td.style.cssText=on;
}
if(this.a==5){
this.table.style.height="50%";
this.table.style.overflow="scroll";
}
}
}
```

La idea es hacer una clase llamada PopupMenu. Que al llamar al metodo __ INIT __ Se creará las bases y se agregará al body, Introducciendo un evento para que cuando el usuario precione 2 veces en la pantalla aparesca el menú. **Aqui esta el ploblema: En internet explorer parese que no escucha ese evento y nunca aparece el menu**. Seguimos con el codigo: Al llamar al metodo createItem se cree un item agregandolo al final de la tabla.

En Chrome me funciona perfectamente, ¡pero al abrirlo con Internet Explorer no!. La verdad me gustaria asegurar la copatibilidad con todos los navegadores posible. Pero no logro dar con el ploblema.
¿Me ayudan?.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120614/discussion-on-question-by-daniel-briceno-por-que-este-codigo-html-y-js-no-funci).

Comment: Si quieres dejar un comentario sobre IE/Edge y la necesidad de darle (o no) soporte, deja un mensaje en el chat enlazado en el comentario de arriba. Usemos los comentarios para temas directamente relacionados con la pregunta.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Listo. Y te dejé una pregunta.